# In What situation the code behind the for-of won't be excuted？

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is the code:

```js
function test(){

  const obj = {a:1,b:2}
 for(const [_,value] of Object.entries(obj) ){
    if(value === xxx){
  // do something
 }

  console.log('finish')  // won't be excuted
}
```

I'm very confused about this, I can't see any would break the `for-of`  and end the function

Comment: if there is an early return then the next lines wont be executed ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
  const obj = {a:1,b:2}
 for(const [_,value] of Object.entries(obj) ){
    if(value === 'xxx'){
 }
  console.log('finish')  
}
```

your code doesn't close the function (where the close }) and xxx also gives you error as you dont have any variable named xxx.

try this :

```
function test() {
  const obj = {a:1,b:2}
 for(const [_,value] of Object.entries(obj) ){
    if(value === 'xxx'){
 }
  console.log('finish')  
}
};
```